# Can't delete records from a table in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.submitForm = function(){ 
        $scope.users.push({
            fname       : $scope.fname,
            lname       : $scope.lname,
            email       : $scope.email,
            password    : $scope.password,
        });
        $scope.fname = ''; //clear the input after adding
        $scope.lname = '';
        $scope.email = '';
        $scope.password = '';
        localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify($scope.users));
    };
```

I am facing some issues while delete a record from a table using angular js. At the time of deletion its working fine but while refreshing the page it came back.

```
$scope.deleteUser = function(idx){
        console.log(idx);
        deleteUser = $window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the User?');
        if(deleteUser){
            $scope.users.splice(idx, 1);
            console.log($scope.users);
        }

    };
```

Comment: Any code or something would be nice, we can't really help you like this...

Comment: What you describe looks like a successful delete handling event at the client-side without actually removing the record from the database. If "it came back", then it was not "working fine at the time".

Comment: actually I am deleting this record from  local storage not from database.

Comment: In the code example, you are not deleting from local storage. So please amend the code example.

Comment: You are deleting from scope, not from localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.deleteUser = function(idx){
        console.log(idx);
        deleteUser = $window.confirm
             ('Are you sure you want to delete the User?');
        if(deleteUser){
            $scope.users.splice(idx, 1);
            console.log($scope.users);
        }           
    };
```

Here you are not deleting it from localStorage, i am guessing `$scope.users` contains data from the `API`.What you can do is after deleting, you can update the `localStorage` with `$scope.users` again

```
localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify($scope.users));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update your local storage values when you delete an user.

```
$scope.deleteUser = function(idx){
    console.log(idx);
    deleteUser = $window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the User?');
    if(deleteUser){
        $scope.users = $scope.users.splice(idx, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        console.log($scope.users);
    }

};
```